# Common Lisp on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, common-lisp, raspberry-pi4, clisp

I just installed Common Lisp on my Raspberry PI. It is running the last OS (2023-10-10 raspios arm64 lite).

Here is what happens when I run a lisp program of mine:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./testpic 10000
Warning: reserving address range 0x21000c0000...0x7effffffff that contains memory mappings. clisp     might crash later!
Memory dump:
  0x2100000000 - 0x21000bffff
  0x555cd90000 - 0x555d013fff
  0x555d022000 - 0x555d04ffff
  .............
  0x7fa1e8c000 - 0x7fa1e8dfff
  0x7fa1e8e000 - 0x7fa1e8ffff
  0x7fd1fff000 - 0x7fd201ffff
Test count : 3334
    Elapsed time : 4 seconds. 
Test count : 6667
    Elapsed time : 11 seconds. 
Test count : 10000
    Elapsed time : 18 seconds. 
104729
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

The result is as expected, except that I see this annoying "Memory dump" at start.

This is how it looks on a standard PC:

```
dhin@earth:~$ ./testpic 10000
Test count : 3334
    Elapsed time : 1 seconds. 
Test count : 6667
    Elapsed time : 5 seconds. 
Test count : 10000
    Elapsed time : 7 seconds. 
104729
dhin@earth:~$
```

Has anyone seen the same kind of thing before?
Did you find a way to solve it?

Just in case this may be useful.

The testpic code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/clisp

(load "PrimeCoreLib.lisp")


(defun AssertPrimesCount(n)
(do ((prmLstLn (length PrimeList) (length PrimeList)))
    ((< n prmLstLn))
    (AddPrime)))

.......
```

It is in a file called `testpic`.

And I run it by doing in the terminal:

```
$ ./testpic 55
```

After running:

```
$ chmod +x testpic
```

And I just noticed this (running `clisp --version`):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ clisp --version
Warning: reserving address range 0x21000c0000...0x7effffffff that contains memory mappings. clisp     might crash later!
Memory dump:
  0x2100000000 - 0x21000bffff
  0x5580390000 - 0x5580613fff
  0x5580622000 - 0x558064ffff
  ......
  0x7fa4c86000 - 0x7fa4c87fff
  0x7fa4c88000 - 0x7fa4c89fff
  0x7fccdb0000 - 0x7fccdd0fff
GNU CLISP 2.49.93+ (2018-02-18) (built on arm-arm-03.debian.org [172.18.68.114])
Software: GNU C 12.2.0 
gcc -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/clisp-8iWNtn/clisp-2.49.20210628.gitde01f0f=. -fstack-protector     --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -no-integrated-cpp -W -Wswitch -Wcomment     -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit -Wno-sign-compare     -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-shift-negative-value -O2 -fwrapv -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -DNO_ASM    -DENABLE_UNICODE -DDYNAMIC_FFI -DDYNAMIC_MODULES -Wl,-z,relro  libgnu.a  -lreadline -lncurses   -lffcall  -lsigsegv -lunistring  
SAFETY=0 HEAPCODES ONE_FREE_BIT_HEAPCODES WIDE_HARD SPVW_BLOCKS SPVW_MIXED TRIVIALMAP_MEMORY
libsigsegv 2.14
libreadline 8.2
libffcall 2.4
Features: (READLINE REGEXP WILDCARD SYSCALLS I18N LOOP COMPILER CLOS MOP CLISP ANSI-CL COMMON-LISP    LISP=CL INTERPRETER LOGICAL-PATHNAMES SOCKETS GENERIC-STREAMS SCREEN FFI GETTEXT UNICODE    BASE-CHAR=CHARACTER WORD-SIZE=64 UNIX)
C Modules: (clisp i18n syscalls regexp readline)
Installation directory: /usr/lib/clisp-2.49.93+/
User language: ENGLISH
Machine: AARCH64 (AARCH64) raspberrypi [127.0.1.1]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could share how you compiled ```testpic```, and maybe ```testpic.lisp``` too.

Comment: Common Lisp is a language, not an implementation. Typically for a bug report one needs an idea what kind of software (name, version, where you got it from, how you built it, ...) you are using.

Comment: Just in case this may be useful. I added some information to the post. Please take a look.

Comment: Does sbcl work? clisp is ancient.

Comment: I don't know. In fact I have never really used lisp as a compiled language. I just read a bit about compiling lisp programs but I always worked inside the CLISP interpreter or used #!/usr/bin/clisp to run my lisp script from thse command line. I never used SBCL.

Comment: I managed to install `clisp` in a Docker image `hannseman/raspbian` and it does not exhibit this behavior. The `clisp --version` output looks identical to what I see on Ubuntu (similarly in a fresh Docker image). Do you have any local files which might trigger this behavior?

Comment: Relevant? https://gitlab.com/gnu-clisp/clisp/-/merge_requests/6

Comment: Does bumping up the memory size with `-m 10MB` help?

Comment: I made a simple test running: clisp -m 10MB --version it does not change anything. I keep seeing the message.

Comment: Yes the post you mention seems to be related. Of course I'd need to dig deeper. But that means I need to recompile clisp (I presume). Though not impossible, I wouldn't mind find an simpler solution here.

Comment: SBCL runs just fine on Raspberry 64 bit. It is available via package manager. I use it for house automation running 24/7. No problems.